# High pass filter that locks voltage at certain amount until frequency is reached

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, high-pass-filter

I have a sine wave that is biased at about 1.5V DC. I want to create a high pass filter that allows any frequency through greater than 4000Hz.
Want I want my high pass filter to do is to be at 1.5V default with no fluctuation. Then when the frequency is greater than 4kHz, it lets it through.
A long while ago I found this high pass filter online:
[image: active high pass filter circuit]
I cant remember where I found it (I think it was just on Google images) but it does almost what I want. Here's the LTspice simulation:
[image: simulation of above circuit]
Green is my biased sine wave which has an amplitude of 0.1 and a freq of 4kHz. Blue is the output of the high pass filter.
The output does exactly what I want. I stays at a constant voltage and then only increases after the frequency reaches the is greater than a certain amount.
The main issue with this is that the constant voltage is 0 whereas I would like it at 1.5V. I could (and I did last time) add a voltage divider on the output but I feel like it's a bit of a bodge and there must be a better way of doing it.
I also don't know the equations for the different resistors and capacitors so I don't know what the real cut-off frequency is.

How can I achieve my goal without a voltage divider on the output?

Comment: You need bipolar supply for Sallen-Key (or make it bandpass, since you'd be bandwidth limited, anyway). Or multiple feedback, which can be adapted easily for single supply.

Comment: Just eliminate C11 and connect the bottom of R14 to your 1.5V supply. This won't change the AC characteristics of your filter.

Comment: The changes you suggested unfortunately have partially worked. https://imgur.com/a/wW4vHOK . The output is at 1.5V but it's not being cut off like last time.

Comment: @DreamingInsanity Since your opamp has its negative rail at ground, it was clipping the output in your arrangement. Dave's arrangement picked the "easy way" to add 1.5 V to the signal. But in doing so, it brought everything up high enough that the opamp no longer clips. Do you actually ***want*** a clipped signal with the negative-going swings chopped off, a baseline of 1.5 V, and only the positive-going swings allowed through? Or is Dave's solution okay? When you say "partially worked" you've failed to say what "working" actually **IS**.

Comment: @jonk I've been thinking about this for a bit because I'm not actually sure how I want it. I think I would prefer if it was clipped like in my original circuit. Would the best way to do this be using a voltage divider on the output? There's nothing inherently wrong with it I just feel like there's a better way of doing it.